# Can't figure out cursor for loop in a plsql procedure

Tags: for-loop, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am trying to write  a procedure in plsql that takes in two parameters, **month** and **year**. The procedure generates data for a table - loanreport. The procedure generates for all loan types in the loan type table. When the procedure is run it should populate the table with:

1. **Month**
2. **Year**
3. **closed loan amount** (sum of loan amounts of loans with status = 6)   if no loans have status = 6 then closed loan amount is 0.

   4.**Average Closing Period**

Here are the pertinent tables:

```
CREATE TABLE LOANDETAILS 
(LOANNO VARCHAR2(11) primary key, 
    PROPERTYID VARCHAR2(10), 
    CUSTID CHAR(8), 
    LOANTYPE VARCHAR2(20), 
    LOANSTATUSCODE NUMBER(3,0), 
    LOANAMOUNT NUMBER(10,2), 
    RATE NUMBER(5,2), 
    LOANCREATIONDATE DATE, 
    LOANSTATUSDATE DATE,
    constraint loandet_prop_fk foreign key(PROPERTYID) references PROPERTIES(propertyid),
    constraint loandet_cust_fk foreign key(CUSTID) references customers(custid),
    constraint loandet_lt_fk foreign key (LOANTYPE) references loantypes(loantype)
   );
   --insert
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000001','P1000001','C1000001','Conventional',1,87975,9,to_date('26-JUL-2016','DD-MON-YY'),to_date('02-AUG-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000009','P1000009','C1000009','FHA',6,160055,4.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('07-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000010','P1000010','C1000010','VA',2,217600,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('07-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));


CREATE TABLE LOANTYPES
   (ltID char(5) constraint loantypes_pk primary key,
    loantype VARCHAR2(20) constraint loantypes_lt_unique UNIQUE, 
    description VARCHAR2(100),
    active char(1) constraint loantypes_active CHECK (active IN ('Y','N')) -- if loan type is currently being offered
    );
Insert into loantypes values ('LT001', 'VA', 'Service members, veterans or eligible family','Y');
Insert into loantypes values ('LT002', 'FHA', 'Federal Housing Administration eligible loans', 'Y');
Insert into loantypes values ('LT003', 'Conventional', 'Standard loan','Y');
Insert into loantypes values ('LT004', 'Employee', 'Eligible employees of the organization','Y');
Insert into loantypes values ('LT005', 'Reconstruct', 'Relief work reconstruction','N');

CREATE TABLE LOANTYPEREPORT 
   (LOANTYPE VARCHAR2(20), 
    MONTH number(2,0), 
    YEAR NUMBER(4,0),  
    CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT NUMBER(15,2), 
    AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD NUMBER(5,2),
    constraint loantr_pk PRIMARY KEY (LOANTYPE, RMONTH, RYEAR)
   );
```

I am new to sql and I clearly have some knowledge gaps. I am attempting to create a procedure then would like to make a cursor and iterate over the cursor with a for loop to create the desired report. Here is my incomplete code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE loan_type_report_procedure (Month loantypereport.month%type, Year loantypereport.year%type) AS

CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT l.loantype, 
       loanamount, 
       loancreationdate,  
       loanstatusdate,
       loanstatuscode,
       to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'mm') AS rMonth, 
       to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'YYYY') AS rYEAR
FROM LOANTYPES l
JOIN LOANDETAILS d
ON l.loantype = d.loantype
WHERE Month = to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'mm') 
      AND Year = to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'YYYY')

BEGIN
FOR loan_rec in C1 LOOP
```

As far as my understanding goes for loop goes row by row in the cursor. If I want a final table **loan type report** that contains loantype, month, year, closed loan amount, and average closing period - how do I make that work? Closed loan amount and average closing period are both aggregated on the loan type grouping. Would I use a group by and having in the cursor select statement?

Thank you for your insight

Comment: You may write some thing like the below:INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT l.loantype, 
      SUM (CASE WHEN loanstatuscode = 6 THEN  loanamount ELSE 0 END) loanamount, 
       loancreationdate,  
       loanstatusdate,
       loanstatuscode,
       to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'mm') AS rMonth, 
       to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'YYYY') AS rYEAR
FROM LOANTYPES l
JOIN LOANDETAILS d
ON l.loantype = d.loantype
WHERE Month = to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'mm') 
      AND Year = to_char(LOANCREATIONDATE, 'YYYY')

Comment: Mike I'm not completely sure I understood all your criteria for the duration, but included a couple examples.  If no loans were closed in a month, I left the average `NULL`.  Is this what you had in mind for the average duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to summarize the number of loans by their `LOANTYPE`, for each month, and for the loans that were closed (`LOANSTATUSCODE = 6`), you'd like to `SUM` their amount and record an `AVERAGE` of their loan time span.
From the look of `LOANTYPEREPORT`, it looks like you are planning for this average span to be in a number of days.

To accomplish this, you do not need to use PL/SQL.  This can be done with traditional SQL.  I'm only guessing at what criteria go into deciding a loan's duration, so I'll outline an example below with a couple variations.

In this example, I needed to modify your tables a little, since they reference other tables not included in your post (I dropped `LOANDET_PROP_FK` and `LOANDET_CUST_FK`).

After creating your example tables, create the `LOANTYPEREPORT` table (modified slightly from your example to compile):

```
CREATE TABLE LOANTYPEREPORT
(LOANTYPE VARCHAR2(20),
 MONTH NUMBER(2,0),
 YEAR NUMBER(4,0),
 CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT NUMBER(15,2),
 AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD NUMBER(5,2),
  CONSTRAINT LOANTR_PK PRIMARY KEY (LOANTYPE, MONTH, YEAR)
);
```

Also, I added a little extra data for some FHA and Conventional loans, to help differentiate the `SUM`s and durations in the examples below.

```
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000001','P1000001','C1000001','Conventional',1,87975,9,to_date('26-JUL-2016','DD-MON-YY'),to_date('02-AUG-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000009','P1000009','C1000009','FHA',6,160055,4.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('07-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000010','P1000010','C1000010','VA',2,217600,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('07-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000011','P1000010','C1000010','VA',6,217600,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('07-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000012','P1000010','C1000010','VA',6,111111,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('17-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000013','P1000010','C1000010','VA',2,222222,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000014','P1000010','C1000010','Conventional',6,333333,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-JAN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000015','P1000010','C1000010','Conventional',5,333333,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-FEB-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000016','P1000010','C1000010','Conventional',4,333333,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-MAR-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000017','P1000010','C1000010','FHA',4,444444,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-APR-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000018','P1000010','C1000010','FHA',6,200000,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-APR-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000019','P1000010','C1000010','FHA',6,300000,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('27-MAY-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
Insert into LOANDETAILS values ('L1000000020','P1000010','C1000010','FHA',6,300000,7.5,to_date('30-NOV-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('22-MAY-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

Then, you can load the report table.
**Example 1**  This assumes that only closed loans should be included in the loan-duration average, that the loan-duration is between `LOANCREATIONDATE` and `LOANSTATUSDATE`, and that you only want data for months and loan-types where loans were actually closed.  This means july 2016 will not be included at all, since no loans were closed in that month.

```
INSERT INTO LOANTYPEREPORT
  SELECT
    LOANDETAILS.LOANTYPE,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE) AS MONTH,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE) AS YEAR,
    SUM(LOANDETAILS.LOANAMOUNT) AS CLOSED_LOAN_AMOUNT,
    AVG(LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE - LOANDETAILS.LOANCREATIONDATE) AS AVERAGE_LOAN_DURATION
  FROM LOANDETAILS
    WHERE LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSCODE = 6
  GROUP BY
    LOANDETAILS.LOANTYPE,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE),
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE);
```

Then see what it did:

```
SELECT YEAR,MONTH,LOANTYPE,CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT,AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD
FROM LOANTYPEREPORT
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH, LOANTYPE;


YEAR  MONTH  LOANTYPE      CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT  AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD  
2016  12     FHA           160055             7                     
2016  12     VA            328711             12                    
2017  1      Conventional  333333             58                    
2017  4      FHA           200000             148                   
2017  5      FHA           600000             175.5
```

**Example 2:** But if you want to include data for months where no loans were closed for a given loan-type (I'm not sure but this might be the third item in your post), then you'll need to enumerate the months.
You can do this several ways, but I'll just include an extra query in this example that sets boundaries for the for 2016 - 2018.

Run the insert:

```
INSERT INTO LOANTYPEREPORT
  WITH YEAR_MONTH AS(
     SELECT THE_MONTH.MONTH_NUMBER,
       THE_YEAR.YEAR_NUMBER
     FROM
       (SELECT LEVEL AS MONTH_NUMBER FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 13) THE_MONTH
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT YEAR_NUMBER FROM
         (SELECT LEVEL AS YEAR_NUMBER FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 2019)
       WHERE YEAR_NUMBER BETWEEN 2016 AND 2018) THE_YEAR
  )
  SELECT
    LOANTYPES.LOANTYPE,
    YEAR_MONTH.MONTH_NUMBER,
    YEAR_MONTH.YEAR_NUMBER,
    SUM(COALESCE(CLOSED_LOAN.LOANAMOUNT,0)) AS CLOSED_LOAN_AMOUNT,
    AVG(CLOSED_LOAN.LOAN_DURATION) AS AVERAGE_LOAN_DURATION
  FROM
    YEAR_MONTH
    CROSS JOIN LOANTYPES
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE) AS MONTH,
                              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE) AS YEAR,
                         LOANDETAILS.LOANTYPE,
                         LOANDETAILS.LOANAMOUNT,
                         LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE - LOANDETAILS.LOANCREATIONDATE AS LOAN_DURATION
                       FROM LOANDETAILS
  WHERE LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSCODE = 6) CLOSED_LOAN
    ON YEAR_MONTH.YEAR_NUMBER = CLOSED_LOAN.YEAR
AND YEAR_MONTH.MONTH_NUMBER = CLOSED_LOAN.MONTH
    AND LOANTYPES.LOANTYPE = CLOSED_LOAN.LOANTYPE
    GROUP BY YEAR_NUMBER, MONTH_NUMBER, LOANTYPES.LOANTYPE
ORDER BY YEAR_NUMBER, MONTH_NUMBER, LOANTYPES.LOANTYPE;
```

And see what data is generated:

```
YEAR  MONTH  LOANTYPE      CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT  AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD  
2016  1      Conventional  0                                        
2016  1      Employee      0                                        
2016  1      FHA           0                                        
2016  1      Reconstruct   0                                        
2016  1      VA            0                                        
2016  2      Conventional  0                                        
...
...
...
2016  12     Conventional  0                                        
2016  12     Employee      0                                        
2016  12     FHA           160055             7                     
2016  12     Reconstruct   0                                        
2016  12     VA            328711             12                    
2017  1      Conventional  333333             58                    
2017  1      Employee      0                                        
2017  1      FHA           0                      
2017  4      FHA           200000             148                   
2017  4      Reconstruct   0                                        
2017  4      VA            0                                  
2017  5      Conventional  0                                        
2017  5      Employee      0                                        
2017  5      FHA           600000             175.5                 
2017  5      Reconstruct   0                                        
2017  5      VA            0                                        
2017  6      Conventional  0                                        
2017  6      Employee      0                                        
2017  6      FHA           0
```

This way you get sum of closing amounts for loans closed each month of each type, or zero if none were closed.

**EDIT with an example of returning from a function.**

Just to reiterate, you do not need to use a function to do this kind of reporting.
But if you have a requirement to use a function, here is an example:

First, create your return type:

```
CREATE TYPE LOAN_TYPE_MONTH_REPORT IS OBJECT (
  LOANTYPE VARCHAR2(20),
  MONTH number(2,0),
  YEAR NUMBER(4,0),
  CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT NUMBER(15,2),
  AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD NUMBER(5,2)
);
/

CREATE TYPE LOAN_TYPE_MONTH_REPORT_LIST IS TABLE OF LOAN_TYPE_MONTH_REPORT;
/
```

Then create your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_LOAN_TYPE_REPORT_FOR_MONTH(P_YEAR IN NUMBER, P_MONTH IN NUMBER)
  RETURN LOAN_TYPE_MONTH_REPORT_LIST
  IS
  V_MONTH_REPORT LOAN_TYPE_MONTH_REPORT_LIST;
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      LOAN_TYPE_MONTH_REPORT(
         THE_MONTH_YEAR.LOANTYPE,
         THE_MONTH_YEAR.THE_MONTH,
         THE_MONTH_YEAR.THE_YEAR,
         COALESCE(CLOSED_LOAN_SUMMARY.CLOSED_LOAN_AMOUNT,0),
         CLOSED_LOAN_SUMMARY.AVERAGE_LOAN_DURATION)
    BULK COLLECT INTO V_MONTH_REPORT
    FROM
      (SELECT P_YEAR AS THE_YEAR, P_MONTH AS THE_MONTH, LOANTYPES.LOANTYPE FROM LOANTYPES) THE_MONTH_YEAR
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT
         LOANDETAILS.LOANTYPE,
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE) AS THE_MONTH,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE) AS THE_YEAR,
         SUM(LOANDETAILS.LOANAMOUNT) AS CLOSED_LOAN_AMOUNT,
         AVG(LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE - LOANDETAILS.LOANCREATIONDATE) AS AVERAGE_LOAN_DURATION
       FROM LOANDETAILS
       WHERE LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSCODE = 6
       GROUP BY
         LOANDETAILS.LOANTYPE,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE),
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LOANDETAILS.LOANSTATUSDATE)) CLOSED_LOAN_SUMMARY
        ON THE_MONTH_YEAR.THE_YEAR = CLOSED_LOAN_SUMMARY.THE_YEAR
           AND THE_MONTH_YEAR.THE_MONTH = CLOSED_LOAN_SUMMARY.THE_MONTH
           AND THE_MONTH_YEAR.LOANTYPE = CLOSED_LOAN_SUMMARY.LOANTYPE;
    RETURN V_MONTH_REPORT;
  END;
  /
```

Then test it:
Here's a month with two loan-types with closings:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(GET_LOAN_TYPE_REPORT_FOR_MONTH(2016,12));
LOANTYPE      MONTH  YEAR  CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT  AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD  
Employee      12     2016  0                                        
VA            12     2016  328711             12                    
Reconstruct   12     2016  0                                        
FHA           12     2016  160055             7                     
Conventional  12     2016  0
```

Or a month with just one loan-type with a closing:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(GET_LOAN_TYPE_REPORT_FOR_MONTH(2017,01));
LOANTYPE      MONTH  YEAR  CLOSEDLOANSAMOUNT  AVERAGECLOSINGPERIOD  
Employee      1      2017  0                                        
Reconstruct   1      2017  0                                        
FHA           1      2017  0                                        
VA            1      2017  0                                        
Conventional  1      2017  333333             58
```

Comment: Hi Alex, than you again for the detailed answer. I appreciate your time and can guarantee that it is helping me wrap my head around SQL. If i want to turn this into a procedure with month and year inputs that spits out the report do you have any insight into that?

Comment: Thanks @Mike Sure thing I can take a look.  Some more detail about the goal and any problems encountered would help.   Can you tell me, what do you want the procedure to do with the inputs?  Are you looking for the procedure to load the report data for only that month-year or for all the history up to that month-year?  Is there a requirement that a single procedure load the table and return data, or should the loading and the query be two separate procedures?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Alex, it would be one procedure with month and year as input. It id to return a report for only that month and year. The returned table would contain the month, year,  closed loan amount and average closing period. The closed loan amount and average closing period only pertain to loans that have status = 6. If there are no loans of status = 6 then closed loan amount and average closing period should be 0. The issue i am having in my solution above is that I do not know how to loop over a cursor and then aggregate the data by loan type

Comment: Ok @Mike I'll update my post with an example and let you know.

Comment: @Mike I have added an example returning a report for a single month from a function.  As I pointed out in my original post, you do not need pl/sql for this kind of reporting, but hopefully this can give you an example if you are required to use pl/sql in your case.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: thank you, that answer is full of good things for me to chew on. I appreciate the time that you have put into helping me. I am going to try to solve it by iterating over a cursor as well. This would give three ways to skin this cat.